# Building TensorFlow Lite with all TF ops?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

How can I build the C++ TensorFlow Lite runtime library with *all* the [select TF operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select)? I can't feed in a model at build time to selectively build a subset.

I'd like a cross-platform solution but for my immediate development needs, I am on macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the TFLite runtime with the flex delegate as dependency, specifically this [rule](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fc4021a8dd654606cd95e61a033691157853e122/tensorflow/lite/delegates/flex/BUILD#L105).
This bazel [macro](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fc4021a8dd654606cd95e61a033691157853e122/tensorflow/lite/delegates/flex/build_def.bzl#L304) builds a shared library for android and if no models specified will link all allowed Select TF ops, you can use it as an example.